# Error in Facebook Android sdk while login

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I found a problem in facebook sdk of android ,after login with facebook android sdk  in samsung  i5830 phone got a error "error on line 2 at column 169 : EntityRef: expecting ':' " .I think its a phone specific because same thing is working fine my other phone like samsung  i9000 and this problem is coming from last 10 to 15 days before that it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

May be there is some problem in facebook server side.Facebook frequently do changes in server side, so try latest face